# How to use "\n" to change line but still print rest of the elements in single line

Tags: python

Using code below -

```
x = ['a', 'b', 'c', '\n', 'a1', 'b1', 'c1']
for i in x :
    print(i , end = " ")
```

I want to get the output  -

```
a b c
a1 b1 c1
```

Currently it shifts a1 by one space -

```
a b c
 a1 b1 c1
```

If i don't use `end =" "` all elements are printed in their own line.

Comment: Check if `i` is `\n` before printing and use `end = ""` if so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, I would look to use `str.join()` instead of looping through individual elements, e.g.:

```
for i in x:
    print(i, end=' ')
```

Is nearly equivalent to (ignoring the spurious space at the end for the above):

```
print(' '.join(x))
```

But you have a small wrinkle in that it also surrounds the `'\n'` with spaces so you want to replace `' \n '` with `'\n'`, so:

```
In []:
print(' '.join(x).replace(' \n ', '\n'))

Out[]:
a b c
a1 b1 c1
```

Or you can get a little over engineered and consider this a problem of splitting the list on a value (in this case `'\n'`) and then printing out the groups:

```
In []:
import itertools as it
print('\n'.join(' '.join(g) for k, g in it.groupby(x, lambda a: a == '\n') if !k))

Out[]:
a b c
a1 b1 c1
```

Comment: First solution to join /replace works just fine... Could you please look at the solution i found on my own ?

Comment: If your solution works for you then use it. It doesn't quite give the same output as you eliminated the space between elements on the second row. I would probably combine a `join` with `format` if you are looking for a more tabular output, there are plenty of examples on SO showing how.

Answer (score 3):

```
x = ['a', 'b', 'c', '\n', 'a1', 'b1', 'c1']
for i in x :
    print(i , end = " " if i != '\n' else '')
```

Answer (score 0):

I kind of found another solution myself... so this works too .. kind of  -  can you guys suggest on this.

```
x = ['a', 'b', 'c', '\n', 'a1', 'b1', 'c1']

y = ""
for i in x:
    y = y + i.rjust(2,)
    
print(y)
```

output -

```
 a b c 
a1b1c1
```

Answer (score 0):

Created also next fancy solution just for fun:

```
x = ['a', 'b', 'c', '\n', 'a1', 'b1', 'c1']
print(*map(lambda s: s + (' ', '')[s.endswith('\n')], x), sep = '')
```

It takes into account the fact that in order to print a list of strings `x` you just need to do:

```
print(*x)
```

which is same and the shortest way to do what was done by the initial questioner's next code:

```
for i in x :
    print(i , end = " ")
```

This `*` operation is called [unpacking](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#tut-unpacking-arguments).